# Where do I find library paths for Build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there any kind of centralized directory for library paths for `Build.sbt` or some standard discovery method? For example, I currently need to use `javax.crypto` in my Scala project and I have no idea what path to write in my `Build.sbt`

Comment: http://search.maven.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sbt uses the standard Maven2 repository by default. If your dependency
>   isn't on one of the default repositories, you'll have to add a
>   resolver to help Ivy find it.

Source: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#resolvers